# xslt2 remove specified part from node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to strip unwanted content from some list items in my html. Basically I want to strip all content before a given span (with class tab), but only if the content before this span matches some criteria.

Take for instance below example :

```
<ol class="ast">
  <li>*<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some blabla <img href="#">with a link.</a></li>
  <li>**<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
</ol>
```

What I like to get is the following :

```
<ol class="ast">
  <li>Some blabla <img href="#">with a link.</a></li>
  <li>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
</ol>
```

or, to explain in words, if I have a list item, starting with one or more asterisk, followed by a tab span, then keep only the content after the span.

I've been fooling around a bit but wasn't able to find something satisfying my needs, so any advice is welcome again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The currently accepted solution is incorrect and generally produces incorrect results. For example, when applied on this XML file**:

```
<ol class="ast">
  <li><a href="#">with a link.</a>*<span class="tab">Some blabla </span></li>
  <li>Something else</li>
</ol>
```

**this incorrect result (`span` and text are incorrectly deleted) is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ol class="ast">
  <li><a href="#">with a link.</a></li>
  <li>Something else</li>
</ol>
```

**Here is one correct solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "li/node()[1]
     [self::text() and not(translate(.,'*',''))
     and following-sibling::node()[self::span[@class='tab']]
     ]"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "li/node()[2]
      [self::span[@class='tab']
     and preceding-sibling::node()[1]
             [self::text() and not(translate(.,'*',''))]
      ]
 "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<ol class="ast">
  <li>*<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some blabla <a href="#">with a link.</a></li>
  <li>Not asterisks!<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li>**<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li>***<span>hello</span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
</ol>
```

**this transformation produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<ol class="ast">
  <li>*<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some blabla <a href="#">with a link.</a></li>
  <li>Not asterisks!<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li>**<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li>***<span>hello</span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
</ol>
```

**When applied on the first XML document above:**

```
<ol class="ast">
    <li><a href="#">with a link.</a>*<span class="tab">Some blabla </span>
    </li>
    <li>Something else</li>
</ol>
```

**again the correct result is produced:**

```
<ol class="ast">
   <li>
      <a href="#">with a link.</a>*<span class="tab">Some blabla </span>
   </li>
   <li>Something else</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li/node()[1]
                                  [self::text() and 
                                   matches(., '^\*+$') and
                                   following-sibling::node()[1]
                                            [self::span and @class = 'tab']
                                   ]" />
    <xsl:template match="li/node()[2]
                                  [self::span and @class = 'tab']
                                  [matches(preceding-sibling::text(), '^\*+$')]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input:

```
<ol class="ast">
  <li>*<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some blabla <a href="#">with a link.</a></li>
  <li>Not asterisks!<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li>**<span class="tab"><!--tab--></span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li>***<span>hello</span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li><a href="#">with a link.</a>*<span class="tab">Some blabla </span></li>
</ol>
```

The result is:

```
<ol class="ast">
  <li>Some blabla <a href="#">with a link.</a></li>
  <li>Not asterisks!<span class="tab"/>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li>***<span>hello</span>Some other blabla, this one without other elements</li>
  <li><a href="#">with a link.</a>*<span class="tab">Some blabla </span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Works on this input, but from the prose problem statement I would have used following-sibling::*[1][self::span] rather than following-sibling::span, and similarly for the preceding-sibling. However, I may have misinterpreted the requirements - I often do.

Comment: I understand there are situations where the solution may not work, but within the structure of my documents it would be ok, though with room for improvement. Just stating that it's maybe a bit hard to down vote, as in essence the solution was correct for the given problem

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you for the suggestion. I agree with you about the `following-sibling::*[1]` and have adjusted my answer accordingly. As for the `preceding-sibling`, the assumption is that the two nodes under scrutiny are the first and second siblings of the `li`, so it doesn't need a `[1]` there, but I did need to add a `node()[2]` earlier in the XPath.